# Making Changes to orangesinglelevel.master

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Okay so ive been attempting to make some customizations to the orangesinglelevel.master with sharepoint designer. When i open the my site in sharepoint designer and navigate to the _catalogs folder and attempt to make changes to the default.master page. None of the changes are shown on the website. I've also tried going to the 'site settings > master galleries > edit with sharepoint designer' but that opens the same default.master page and still no changes are evident.

I have almost no clue how to edit the information that is being displayed on the website and i have absolutely no clue where it is coming from.

Is there a difference between master pages and themes? im i making changes to the theme and not the master page? please any help would be much appreciated i cannot implmenent any of my ideas because i have no clue what information is being display.

Also when i click design view inside of sharepoint designer it does not display the orange theme.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your changes in master page are checked in and published.

Click on Site Actions -> Site Settings, and then under Look and Feel, click Master page. Here you can change both system as well as site master page.

P.S. It is recommend not to change the default.master and instead make and copy of it and customize it.

Comment: both the system and the site are set to orangeSingleLevel.master. but still no changes are evident in sharepoint designer.

Comment: if you're using the Custom theme then make  sure that place the custom theme information file in the following location _C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\THEMES_  folder http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=122